# Any setpixel example?

Tags: javascript, paperjs

I'm trying to understand how to use **setpixel** method that exists in the PaperJS code and its documentation but doesn't work.

Here is the [Sketch example](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#V/prebuilt/S/TY7NDoIwEIRfZVMvEH6KBy+oJx/Bo/VQcREF22bbaAnh3W1JNO5p5pvsZCam5BNZzY49uqZjOWv0NXqhhOK8c87UnBtpkB621HTjhC0SqgY5SeuQ+MqiM3ePQ+GLsWj0oCm+whcnPh/zBaexVKiXJFg87EHhGw5RJ1W5CXkbaOJDUG3Bww7WVRRZlk5CQbi/0upXOofZF0LZG31XzrL6dJ4/).

Comment: Don't add links to code you have, paste the code you have here and explain what you're trying to do and the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This method is made to be used on a raster instance.
Extracted from the [documentation](http://paperjs.org/reference/raster/#raster-size), here is a [sketch](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#V/prebuilt/S/VVFBbsIwEPzKKicjIpPeKigXkHrqoSrH0oNxNsTBsaN4C6WIv3cdh5ZasjJez+7MxJfMqRazebY5IOk6yzPty3jW3gWCkymphiU8FMVi229dqtZo9jXdleOezWDdoyIE5QDbjs7Qq0DYQ2eVxhIUwdHgCTQ6rsq/cSNtCY5v34aDiHBjvlEMDvJRcjIZ5FKDDK33VBu359ZK2YD3Xp59D8pa8BUYCtCZL7RBykG24jthkcBwZ7Hgz1NKynA6ncAlkoDXL7FJxIaJyQnjf8y4WJUFAtMVZ3Klb0F761PUG+nmHek1WhImhyaH9cBLTWJMGdnXCK63WF3vG9QklSZzxBd15kGVoZX/dGUQ8efK3YBl0MqiKOTjOIvfdcePc+i8cRSy+fvH9Qc=) demonstrating what it does.

```
const width = 100;
const height = 100;

// Create an empty raster placed at view center.
const raster = new Raster(new Size(width, height));
raster.smoothing = false;

// For all of its pixels...
for (let i = 0; i < width; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < height; j++) {
        // ...set a random color.
        raster.setPixel(i, j, Color.random());
    }
}

project.activeLayer.fitBounds(view.bounds.scale(0.8));
```

Comment: Oh, I see. Thanks! :)